# How to use Google Drive Api in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

For the past few days I've been trying to upload and download files from Google Drive using Java. I've seen some tutorials on the internet but they all used Gradle and I need to do this in Eclipse. I can't use Gradle because it does not work with other parts of the project.
Does anyone know how to upload/download files in Google Drive using Java (Eclipse Neon)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Maven or just simply add the Drive client library to your project. Check out this page for Maven/download links:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2

Once you have the necessary jar in your project, you should be able to follow the existing tutorials on how to use Drive, e.g.:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/examples/